# Solve multi-objective optimization problem with R package rmoo

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

The documentation to this packages is available [here](https://mirror.nju.edu.cn/pub/pub/CRAN/web/packages/rmoo/rmoo.pdf), but for me it is impossible to transfer my *real-valued* 3 objective function to a form that it works.

I'm trying to solve it with the `nsga2` function - and I think `nsga3` should work the same way?!

My objective functions, which I want to minimize, are:

```
f1 <- 1640.2823 + 2.3573285*x[1] + 2.3220035*x[2] +4.5688768*x[3] + 7.7213633*x[4] + 4.4559504*x[5]
  
f2 <- 6.5856 + 1.15*x[1] - 1.0427*x[2] + 0.9738*x[3] + 0.8364*x[4] - 0.3695*x[1]*x[4] + 0.0861*x[1]*x[5] + 0.3628*x[2]*x[4] - 0.1106*x[1]^2 - 0.3437*x[3]^2 + 0.1764*x[4]^2
  
f3 <- -0.0551 + 0.0181*x[1] + 0.1024*x[2] + 0.0421*x[3] - 0.0073*x[1]*x[2] + 0.024*x[2]*x[3] - 0.0118*x[2]*x[4] - 0.0204*x[3]*x[4] - 0.008*x[3]*x[5] - 0.0241*x[2]^2 + 0.0109*x[4]^2
```

And x has to be between one and three (these are the constraints)

```
1 <= x[i] <= 3
```

I appreciate any hints... so many thanks in advance!

Comment: I am working on something similar - take a look at my profile and see if something could help you from there?

Comment: I am looking on github to see if something there can help: https://github.com/Evolutionary-Optimization-Laboratory/rmoo

Comment: https://rdrr.io/github/Evolutionary-Optimization-Laboratory/rmoo/man/nsga2.html I am trying to see if you can add constraints?